# Sorting files and directories differently in the file browser

Tags: nautilus, directory, file-sorting

Is it possible for the file browser to, for example, sort files by Modified date and directories alphabetically?

I never care about the most recently modified directory and can find the one I want faster if they are sorted alphabetically, but this is the opposite for files.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible, in Nautilus, to have a different sorting for directories and folders in the same window. You can open two windows and maintain a different sorting order in each of the windows, though.